# Value for optional parameter by name (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function like this

```
function drawImageOnCanvas(canvas, texturePath, color, type, onCall, modelPath, scene, pX, pY, pZ, scale, transform) {}
```

Here `onCall, modelPath, scene, pX, pY, pZ, scale, transform` are optional parameters. How can i pass value only for `scale`. Is there any way to define parameter name and pass value?

Comment: Use an object instead of bunch of arguments...

Comment: Or if you feel you *must* have separate arguments rather than using an object, pass `undefined` for the arguments you're wanting to skip. Either way, the function will have to test which values it has received and act accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an object as the function's parameter.

```
function drawImageOnCanvas(canvas, options){
    var scale = options.scale;
}
```

And in call site:

```
drawImageOnCanvas(canvas, {scale: 2});
```

Also to handle optional parameters, you can check their existence using an `if` or `||` or `?:`.

```
var color = /*default color*/;
if (options.color){
    color = options.color;
}
```

Or

```
var color = options.color || /*default color*/;
```

Or

```
var color = options.color ? options.color : /*default color*/;
```

**Note:** If `options` contains parameters having `false`, `0`, etc values then the methods above are not suitable anymore. For example, assume we have a parameter called `isActive`, then passing `{isActive: false}` will lead to the `/*default isActive*/`. To address this problem, you can use `.hasOwnProperty` or `in`.

```
var options = {scale: 2, isActive: false};

console.log('isActive' in options); // true
console.log(options.hasOwnProperty('isActive')); // true
console.log(options.isActive); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you have a function with many optional parameters, a much better option is to use a single parameter for all the optional parameters as an object.

In ES6, this case be more easily accomplished using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) and [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

```
function drawImageOnCanvas(canvas, {scale = 1} = {}) {
    ...
}
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
drawImageOnCanvas(canvas, { scale: 2 });
```

```js
function test({ x = 10 } = {}) {
  console.log(x);
}

test({ x: 100 }); // passing x
test({ y: 200 }); // not passing x
test();           // not passing anything still works
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an array having `.length` equal to the number of expected parameters to function, set parameters passed to function as elements of an array, set index `10` of array to value for `scale`, use rest element to pass array of parameters to function, destructuring assignment within function to define named variables

```js
function drawImageOnCanvas(canvas, texturePath, color, type, onCall
, modelPath, scene, pX, pY, pZ, scale, transform) {
      console.log(canvas, texturePath, color, type, scale);
}

var args = Array.of(document.createElement("canvas"), 1, 2, 3, ...Array(7));

args[10] = {scale:456};

drawImageOnCanvas(...args);
```